# Celery tasks uncaught exceptions not being sent to Sentry

Tags: django, exception, logging, celery, sentry

I'm currently working with Celery tasks in a Django based project. We have raven configured to send all uncaught exceptions and log messages to Sentry, as described in the [documentation](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integrations/django.html).

Everything works pretty good, except for uncaught exceptions inside celery tasks. For example, if I run this task:

```
@app.task
def test_logging():
    log.error('Testing logging inside a task')
    raise IndexError('Testing exception inside a task')
```

I only see in Sentry the `log.error(...)` but not the `IndexError` uncaught exception.
I've tried using a `try-except` block around the exception with a `log.exception(...)` inside and it did work, but I think it's not scalable to catch all exceptions like this.

So, the problem are only uncaught exceptions that somehow are not handled properly.

These are my current package versions:

```
celery (3.1.17)
raven (5.1.1)
Django (1.7.1)
```

Would you help me to move in some direction?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: have you already tried http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integrations/celery.html  and http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-hijack-root-logger ?

Comment: Thanks DRC, finally the solution using `register_signal(client)` worked, and now we see uncaught exceptions logged correctly in Sentry. Cheers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As described by DRC in the comment up there, we finally got to the solution using this approach:
https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/celery/

Basically doing this:

```
import celery

class Celery(celery.Celery):

    def on_configure(self):
        if hasattr(settings, 'RAVEN_CONFIG') and settings.RAVEN_CONFIG['dsn']:
            import raven
            from raven.contrib.celery import (register_signal,
                                              register_logger_signal)

            client = raven.Client(settings.RAVEN_CONFIG['dsn'])
            register_logger_signal(client)
            register_signal(client)


app = Celery('myapp')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In which file do you write this configuration for celery to read it?

Comment: I have a dedicated `celery.py` module where all the celery configuration is located. Then that configuration is imported in other module `tasks.py` where I have all the tasks defined.

Comment: What's the alternative for their new `sentry-sdk` API?

Answer (score 9):

The chosen answer is correct as the question states `raven` is being used.
However raven has been deprecated in favour of the sentry SDK.

To configure `django` and `celery` with the sentry SDK:

First add `sentry-sdk` to your requirements file.

Then, in your django setttings file:

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration
from sentry_sdk.integrations.celery import CeleryIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="your_sentry_DSN",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), CeleryIntegration()],
    send_default_pii=True
)
```

Sources:

- Get your DSN: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#setting-the-dsn
- Sentry Django integration: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/django/
- Sentry Celery integration: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/celery/

Comment: Hi, I have added these changes to my code but it is not capturing celery task errors. Is any other changes are needed in the codebase. Can you please help?@guival

Comment: @Anjitha No, that should be it. Is it correctly capturing other errors?

Comment: Yes, It's tracking all errors that are not related to celery. Is there any additional settings in the celery configuration file?

Comment: @Anjitha Can't think of anything right now, maybe you should open your own question.

Comment: @gdvalderrama I propose making a new question for `sentry-sdk` (and [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your answer here).  The chosen answer was framed in the context of the legacy raven package and has an answer catered to that.  They're different packages.